# I got an error message when I try to update my nativescript Project

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, cross-platform, nativescript-codesharing

I try to update my native script project  when I  try to run

```
tns update next
```

I got The error

```
Could not update the project! Reason is: rm: could not remove file (code EBUSY): C:/work/MyProject/zero/angular/platforms/android/build-tools/runSbg.log
```

my `tns info` is

```
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
‼ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 6.4.0 and the latest available version is 6.8.0.
‼ Update available for component tns-core-modules. Your current version is 6.4.2 and the latest available version is 6.5.13.
‼ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 6.4.1 and the latest available version is 6.5.3.
× Component tns-ios is not installed.
```

I am using Nativescript with Angular  and it is code sharing project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely **due to a running process that is using the file**. To fix this, make sure you have ended all your processes that is running Nativescript or in this case android. If you are not sure, you can restart your PC.

Afterwards, if you want to do a fresh update/install; Go to your project root folder and then delete the Nativescript Generated folders: **hooks**, **node_modules**, and **platforms**.

Once that is done, you will now have a clean slate to update your project by:

```
tns update next
```